# Something keeps writing lots of data on disk and causes me to run out of space

Tags: disk-usage

On my Ubuntu 16.04 (guest system, VirtualBox) something is clogging up my disk lately. To the point of only 126 MB space left. It happened now for three days in a row. I delete 2 GB or more files to make space. After a few hours space is gone and I have no clue what is causing it...

The only thing that comes to mind is that I was trying to install .Net 4.5 (and other versions) in Wine unsuccessfully many times in past few days and maybe there are some files being left somewhere (where?)...

Any ideas on what and how to look for highly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: It smells like something is logging like crazy.

Answer (score 0):

On your VM you can type `du -sh /*` this would list the usage of each directory, then you could just continue to which directories look large and look inside those.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately this will not help since I have some huge directories with lots of data I need to analyze in them. Any ideas to see which files/directories are growing?

Comment: Add a `watch` before the command to see which are growing.